# How to stack or wrap code tabs in IntelliJ window

Tags: intellij-idea

If there are more code tabs than can fit in a window, can the tabs be configured to stack or wrap around so they are all visible?

e.g.

```
-------------
tab1 | tab2 |
tab3 | tab4 |
-------------
```

vs

```
--------------------
tab1 | tab2 | tab3 |
--------------------
```

**edit**

Shortest solution for me was

> right click on a tab -> click "Tabs Placement" -> uncheck "Show Tab in Single Row"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Which version are you using? In 2018.2 this option is right there, just right click on tabs and unclick **Tabs Plaement** > **Show Tabs In Sinble Row**:

[image]

So they look following way:

[image]

Comment: Nice. I just right clicked on a tab -> clicked "Tabs Placement" -> unchecked "Show Tab in Single Row"

Answer (score 4):

FYI option is accessible from small context menu in the new ui version

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is also applicable to Webstorm 2023.1.1

Answer (score 3):

are you talking about the fact that some tabs are automatically closed once you reach a given limit ?

if that's the case you can increase that limit by going to

Preferences > Editor > General > Editor Tabs > Tab Closing Policy

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Hit `Ctrl + Shift + A` and search for *show tabs in single row*.
[image]

Then turn it OFF, so all the tabs will become visible.

From the IntelliJ 2018 help:

> Select ON if you want tab headers to be displayed in a single row. As a result, some tab headers may become invisible.